# retrieve multiple stores in dart

Tags: dart, store, dart-async

I use boilerplate code to retrieve data from 1 store such as

```dart
MonthStore monthStore = new MonthStore();
monthStore.open().then((months) {
```

but I am having difficulty retrieving data from multiple, related stores. Is this the best I can do?

```dart
MonthStore monthStore = new MonthStore();
monthStore.open().then((months) {
  TranStore tranStore = new TranStore();
  tranStore.open().then((trans) {

    // months[trans.monthId].name

  });
});
```

I tried using `Future.wait` like this

```dart
// declare the stores
MonthStore monthStore = new MonthStore();
TranStore tranStore = new TranStore();

Future.wait(
  [
    getMonth(monthStore, intMonth),
    // another call
  ]
)
.then...

Future<Map> getMonth(mnthStore, mnth) {
  mnthStore.open()
    .then((mnths) {
      return mnths[mnth];
    })
  // need a return here!
});
```

but the editor says no return specified in the Future.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
Future<Map> getMonth(mnthStore, mnth) {
  return mnthStore.open() // <= here the return is important
  .then((mnths) {
    return mnths[mnth];
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I was sweating over this for hours.

Comment: And I was wondering for hours why nobody asks any Dart questions today ;-)

Comment: lol. SO is like a dad who tells his child to cut himself first before he shows him how to handle a knife.